# Why am I not getting chat notifications in the top-bar?

Tags: support, chat, notifications, top-bar

I noticed that after the black top bar was added I don't get the chat notifications anymore...

I can see them in `chat.[sitename]` page but I would like to get them in the main pages of the website.

I don't know if this a new feature or a bug, but can you add this back, please?

Comment: I get chat notifications in my top bar, if I don't read them or post in the chat after the mention.

Comment: @3ventic That's nice.. I cannot see them. But if I go to the chat page (chat.stackoverflow.com) I see that green circle with the number of pings.

Comment: It might be specific to chat.SO, while chat.SE works.

Comment: @3ventic No, it doesn't work on any website... :-(

Comment: Might be the same bug as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161168/152859)...

Comment: [I'm not sure what the problem you're facing is - the functionality seems to work as requested already](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ENYiS.jpg).

Comment: @Flyk I don't see the chat messages in the inbox... I can see only the notifications from sites.

Comment: Chat notifications do appear in the inbox on the main site. They are delayed, have you waited long enough? There's a known bug that [the read/unread marking may be incorrect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161168/delayed-chat-notification-causes-wrong-inbox-highlighting).

Comment: @Gilles Voted that, since the new top bar was implemented I don't get the chat notifications... I guessed this is a new feature but this confused me when I saw the unread messages in the chat going to the chat.stackoverflow.com page. How much must I wait until I get the notifications?

Comment: I think the delay is 30min, but I'm not sure. I didn't observe any change in the switch to the new top bar.

Comment: I'm still getting chat notifications today, so this isn't broken for everyone. Can you link to some messages that should have notified you but didn't?

Comment: @Gilles I think that I was actually wrong.. [They have a delay of `20 minutes` - I guess](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214690/205508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It's not really a bug. We [tested this functionality in the meta chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1712470#1712470).

It seems that the chat notifications come in the top navbar after 20 (?) minutes.

Here is what I see after 23 minutes

> [image]

Comment: Wasn't this always the case? Chat notifications have always been delayed by atleast 15 minutes as far as I remember... They are never realtime..

Comment: @Aditya I don't remember this.. The others say that it was always the case.